# How to sort results from UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a query like this:

```
(select @number:=3) 
  union 
(select @number:=2) 
  union 
(select @number:=1) 
order by @number ASC
```

With results:

```
3
2
1
```

But I would like the results in ascending order, like this:

```
1
2
3
```

How can I achieve the results in ascending order with a query like this?

Comment: Are you still trying to figure this out?

Comment: Hi McAdam331 sorry i haven't replied on this. i have used your answer and my problem is solved well.. Thank you very much friend

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the UNION in a subquery, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
   SELECT @number := 3 AS number
   UNION
   SELECT @number := 2 AS number
   UNION
   SELECT @number := 1 AS number) tmp
ORDER BY number;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/2677) example.

---

An edit, to explain what is happening:

In your example, MySQL is treating each group as its own query (which is how you'd expect a union to work) so it is as if you had three different queries, and only the third one is being ordered.

So, by putting the unioned queries together, you have *one* result set, and that entire result set is what is being ordered.

Comment: I was under the impression MySQL used the `ORDER BY` specified by the last select of a UNION query. So, if I am not mistaken, the questioner might have gotten the results they wanted by just removing all those parenthesis.

Comment: @Uueerdo You might be right. It just seemed to me like that was happening. I'll try it out without parents too and see.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
(select @number:=3) 
  union 
(select @number:=2) 
  union 
(select @number:=1) 
order by @number ASC
```

Your `order by` has a constant.  It is `order by "1"` -- `@number` is a variable, not a column name.  Hence, no ordering.  What you want is to specify the number as a column name:

```
select 3 as number
union all
select 2
union all
select 1
order by number;
```

You should also use `union all` instead of `union`, unless you want the additional overhead of removing duplicates.